# How do I find out what powershell script just ran?

Tags: windows-10, security, powershell

I'm running Windows 10. I was reading a web page, when suddenly a window popped up. I got just enough time to see that it was powershell -- then it opened another window, and both disappeared. I had a similar experience yesterday, but it looked more like a cmd shell (white on black).

(The website was LinkedIn, and I keep Firefox locked down pretty tight with NoScript, and popups blocked by default, so I don't think it was the browser.)

How do I find out what ran, and who ran it?

Comment: i don't think you can find that info with the default settings. there is a local GPO setting that activates logging ... i use it ... but without that i don't think you can get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
to catch all execution of `powershell.exe`, by setting the right filter.

For information on using Process Monitor see the How-To Geek article
[Understanding Process Monitor](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson4/).

Note that running Process Monitor while using the computer,
which is what you need to do, may slow your usage of the computer and may
need some disk space.